# Problem with table spacing when aligning by decimal point?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, siunitx

Please see attached MWE and pdf. The problem seems to be with the column 'Test 1'? Any suggestions would be very much appreciated, I have tried altering each variable but I cannot work out where the problem is. Many thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}   
\usepackage{graphicx}           
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\graphicspath{ {paperfigures/} }
\usepackage[font={footnotesize}, margin=2cm]{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}

\centering
\caption{clear test}
\label{tab:cleart}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {\cdot}}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|S[table-format = 3]<{\si{}}
         |*{4}{S[table-format = 3.1,
                 separate-uncertainty,
                 table-space-text-post={\quad},
                 table-figures-uncertainty=1]|}}
\cline{3-6}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} 
&   \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{Intensity 
(mV)}}                                                            \\
\hline
\textbf{Angle}
&   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Height}}
    &   \textbf{Test 1}
        &   \textbf{Test 2}
            &   \textbf{Test 3}  
               & \textbf{Mean}   \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{5\degree}
& Top    & 2.3 \pm 2.0 & 5.8 \pm 2.0 & 8.2 \pm 2.0   &                     
\\ \cline{2-6}
& Middle  & 3.7 \pm 2.0 & 2.9 \pm 2.0 & 26.1 \pm 2.1  &                    
\\ \cline{2-6}
& Bottom & 12.8\pm 2.0 & 4.5 \pm 2.0 & 13.6 \pm 2.0    &                   
\\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{10\degree}
&  Top  & 10.4\pm 2.0 & 8.8 \pm 2.0 & 11.4 \pm 2.0  &                    
\\ \cline{2-6}
& Middle  & 12.5\pm 2.0 & 8.0 \pm 2.0 & 7.2 \pm 2.0  &                     
\\ \cline{2-6}
& Bottom  & 5.3 \pm 2.0 & 2.9 \pm 2.0 & 5.1 \pm 2.0   &                     
\\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{15\degree}
& Top   & 9.6 \pm 2.0 & 6.9 \pm 2.0 & 11.0 \pm 2.0      &                 
\\ \cline{2-6}
& Middle  & 12.2\pm 2.0 & 9.0 \pm 2.0 & 3.5 \pm 2.0  &                     
\\ \cline{2-6}
& Bottom  & 2.3 \pm 2.0 & 2.2 \pm 2.0 & 1.5 \pm 2.0   &                     
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: table]

Answer (score 1):

The result with `S[table-format = 2.1(2)]` as column specification for the third columm:

> [image: Result]

Comment: I am still confused as to why in column 3 entitled 'test 1' the inputs read 2.3 (20) instead of 2.3 ± 2.0 for example? these inputs should look the same as for columns 4 and 5

Comment: @referencingstressesmeout The options for the `S` column of the third column differs from the options of the `S` columns of the next four columns. BTW, there are *seven* column specifications, but only *six* columns are used. Maybe the third column specification is a left-over from previous trials and should be removed.